# Prove that for almost all $x\in [0,1]$ we have $f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k'(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem**. Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of increasing functions on $[0,1]$. Suppose that for each $x\in [0,1]$ the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$ converges to a real number, so that we can define the function $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$. Prove that for almost all $x\in [0,1]$ we have $f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k'(x)$.

---

I would be glad if someone could check my attempt.

**Attempt**. Note that for each $x\in [0,1]$ we have $$f'(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x+1/n)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f_k(x+1/n)-f_k(x)}{1/n}\overset{(1)}{=} \sum_{k=1}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_k(x+1/n)-f_k(x)}{1/n}\overset{(2)}{=}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_k(x+h)-f_k(x)}{h}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k'(x)$$

In fact, I'm not sure how to verify the equalities (1) and (2). And, I'm not sure if there is a special reason to use the expression "for almost all $x\in [0,1]$" in the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This requires a heavy dose of measure theory. You don't even know from basic Calculus that the derivative exists so how do you give  a proof from this kind of argument?

Comment: The "almost all" means on all but a set of measure 0,  which I'm pretty sure is necessary because an increasing function can be non-differentiable on a set of measure 0.

Comment: You may not be able to switch the limit and the summation. Let $a_{m,n}= \frac{1}{m n }$ , $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m,n}=0$ for every $m$ so $\sum_{m} \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{m,n} =0$ but $\sum_{m} a_{m,n}$ does not exist so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{m} a_{m,n}$ does not exist.